# Error only occurring when function is imported from adjacent file

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook, python-import

When I define and call a function within a script it works great. When I import it from an adjacent file I get an error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment"

I have tried including the "return(json_normalize(data))" in the IF statement but it didn't return anything.

The function being imported.

```py
def get_query(query_num):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        params = {'p_param': query_num}
        query_id = query_num
        data = get_fresh_query_result('https://redash.domain.io', query_id, api_key, params)

    return(json_normalize(data))
```

get_fresh_query_result is working fine when imported.

The expected result is a Pandas df. but I am getting an error instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because of the if statement checking whether the current module is `__main__`. This is only the case if the function is in the main script. Remove the `if` statement, and the module can be imported from other places.